# How to add space between labels values and its represented values in a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The following code, plots the black dots. I'd like to create some separation between the black dots and the red label number of each dot.

```
BBU = [41.3822706100000   2.12861183500000;
       41.3951737600000   2.14739148800000;
       41.4053832900000   2.15673183600000;
       41.4083225700000   2.16864721900000;
       41.4032320900000   2.20663354500000;
       41.3939710600000   2.19351888300000;
       41.3821269800000   2.18958664200000;
       41.4188280200000   2.19925787100000;
       41.3591028400000   2.13697455100000;
       41.3813193100000   2.17610240700000;
       41.3891879400000   2.17709430900000;
       41.3932500600000   2.15626943700000;
       41.3838562100000   2.16188867500000;
       41.3720818100000   2.16253718100000;
       41.3768090000000   2.14498916300000;
       41.4001588800000   2.17864126300000;
       41.4204607900000   2.18283805400000;
       41.4010364200000   2.16198599800000];
nr_BBU = 18;
for i=1:nr_BBU
    plot(BBU(i,2), BBU(i,1), 'k.', 'MarkerSize',25)
    labels = cellstr(num2str((i)'));
    text(BBU(i,2), BBU(i,1), labels, 'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
        'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'Color', 'r', 'FontSize', 12)
    hold on
end
```

Actual Plot:

[image: Actual plot]

Comment: put the text in another location.... add an offset for the location for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some offset to one of the coordinates seems to do the job.

```
text(BBU(i,2)+0.001, BBU(i,1),labels,'HorizontalAlignment', ...
   'center','VerticalAlignment', 'bottom',...
   'Color', 'r', 'FontSize',12)
```